# CSS : i don't know how to split this code (for card flip)

Tags: css, rotation, transform, flip

I tried to split this code from :

```
.card-container:hover .sides {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

to this :

```
.card-container:hover {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.sides {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

and it doesn't work.

It's for a card flip without clicking on it (and no js)

Here the full code :

HTML :

```
  <div class="card-container" >
    <div class="sides">
      <div class="front"> NIKE </div>
      <div class="back"> TA RACE</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS :

```
.card-container {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  margin-left: auto;
  max-width: 320px;
  perspective: 100;
  width: 320px;
  height: 480px;
}

.card-container:hover .sides {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}


.sides {
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: .6s;
}
.front {
  width: 320px;
  height: 480px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: yellow;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

.back {
  width: 320px;
  height: 480px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  background-color: green;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Comment: Have you considered reading **anything** about CSS selectors?

Comment: Why are you trying to split this code, that might help us help you.  The original code block says - when you hover over the parent `.card-container`, rotate the child element `.sides`.  Your modified code says - ALWAYS have the child `.sides` rotated, and ALSO when you hover over the parent `.card-container` rotate the parent container.